# Programmatically unpin standard applications from Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I found following script to unpin standard applications from Windows 10 Start Menu, the problem is that it only unpins applications that are already installed. There are also several applications (for example Facebook and Twitter) that are downloaded and installed when you first click on their tile, and this script does not unpin them until they are installed.

Is there a way to unpin these tiles?

```
function Pin-App { param(
  [string]$appname,
  [switch]$unpin
  )
try{
  if ($unpin.IsPresent){
    ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'From "Start" UnPin|Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
    return "App '$appname' unpinned from Start"
  }else{
    ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'To "Start" Pin|Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
    return "App '$appname' pinned to Start"
  }
  }catch{
    Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?)"
  }
}

Pin-App "Mail" -unpin
Pin-App "Store" -unpin
```